# Finding the difference between two DateTimes (hours and minutes)

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm trying to create a simple program that reads in user input for the time they went to sleep and the time they woke up, and output the total time they slept. The output shows up incorrect and I'm unsure what the problem is. I've tried two different codes but they both seem to be having the same problem.

The first code was this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input time you slept");
string sleepTime = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please input the time you woke up");
string wakeTime = Console.ReadLine();

TimeSpan sleepDuration = DateTime.Parse(wakeTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(sleepTime));

Console.WriteLine("You slept for " + sleepDuration + " hours");
Console.ReadKey();
```

My first attempt I used 12:00 AM for sleepTime and 8:00 AM for wakeTime. The output was 8 hours, which is correct. I tried changing the values to 11:00 PM for sleepTime and 7:00 AM for wakeTime and the output was -16:00, which is incorrect as the time between 11:00 PM and 7:00 AM is also 8 hours.

This is the second code I tried using:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input the time you went to sleep");
DateTime sleepTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please input the time you woke up");
DateTime wakeTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

TimeSpan sleepDuration = wakeTime - sleepTime;

Console.WriteLine("You slept for " + sleepDuration + " hours");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I used the exact same times as I did for the first code and got the exact same outputs. 12:00 AM to 8:00 AM outputs 8:00 and 11:00 PM to 7:00 AM outputs -16:00.

What's causing -16:00 to be the output and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you only type in the time of when you woke up? Because surely you did not wake up 7 AM the same day you went to bed at night? ie. you did not sleep causing time to reverse? You need to handle the fact that the two DateTime values are on different dates. Basically you calculated `7-23` and that is `-16` right enough. A simple `if (wakeTime < sleepTime) wakeTime = wakeTime.AddDays(1);` should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that parsing only a time with `DateTime.Parse` defaults the date portion to `DateTime.Today`.

If you input that you went to bed at 23:00 and woke up at 07:00 these values will look like this (for today when I write this answer):

```
2016-01-20 23:00
2016-01-20 07:00
```

Notice it's the same date. `DateTime.Parse` has no knowledge of the context in which you're parsing values and it shouldn't.

Basically you "slept in reverse".

You should handle this like this:

```
if (wakeTime < sleepTime)
    wakeTime = wakeTime.AddDays(1);
```

This will correctly represent the fact that you woke up the following morning, then subtraction will correctly return 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If wakeTime < sleepTime then wakeTime is obviously the next day. You then need to add another day:

```
 if (sleepDuration.TotalHours < 0)
     sleepDuration += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem while using the date time parsing using Date only
you must give date to get the exact solution
other wise

```
TimeSpan sleepDuration=null;
if(wakeTime> sleepTime)
   sleepDuration=  wakeTime - sleepTime;
else
sleepDuration=   sleepTime-wakeTime;
```