# Check the time difference between start time and end time should be 1 hour 30 minutes if its more than that it should not proceed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am scheduling a timetable in asp.net core, I want to keep all the lecture timings to be only 1hour 30 minutes, if by accident or on purpose the class timing is reduced or increased in this time then it should give an error message at run time. the startTime and EndTime have DT DateTime in viewModel and in model its TimeSpan, I have performed parsing to check the Starttime and Endtime of other classes while being scheduled.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(TimetableViewModel timetableViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse( timetableViewModel.StartTime.ToString("hh:mm")); 
        var endTime = TimeSpan.Parse(timetableViewModel.EndTime.ToString("hh:mm"));
        bool matched = false;
        var record = _context.TimeTables.Where(x => x.RoomID == timetableViewModel.RoomID && x.Day == timetableViewModel.Day).ToList();
        foreach (var item in record)
        {
            if ((startTime >= item.StartTime && startTime <= item.EndTime) || (endTime >= item.StartTime && endTime <= item.EndTime) || (startTime <= item.StartTime && endTime >= item.EndTime))
            { 
                matched = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (matched)
        {      //some error message  
        }
        else
        {
            timetableViewModel.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var booking = new TimeTable()
                {
                    TableId = timetableViewModel.TableId,
                    BatchID = timetableViewModel.BatchNumber,
                    ProgrameID = timetableViewModel.ProgrameID,
                    RoomID = timetableViewModel.RoomID,
                    TeacherID = timetableViewModel.TeacherID,
                    SemesterID = timetableViewModel.SemesterID,
                    CourseID= timetableViewModel.CourseID,
                    Day = timetableViewModel.Day,
                    StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse(timetableViewModel.StartTime.ToString("hh:mm")),
                    EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse(timetableViewModel.EndTime.ToString("hh:mm")),
                    IsActive = 1,
                    CreatedOn = timetableViewModel.CreatedOn
                };

                _context.Add(booking);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                TempData["Success"] = "Scheduled Successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the difference between two DateTimes (hours and minutes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893161/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: Im not sure how should i count hours and minutes difference and display the message for user

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but TimeSpan allows you to perform time arithmetic so if you wish to check that a lecture period is 1 hour 30 minutes then surely all you need to do is:

```
string startTime = "10:00";
string endTime ="11:30";

string lecturePeriod = "1:30";

TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse(startTime);
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse(endTime);

bool matched = (end - start) == lecturePeriod;
```

You already state that you validate the times on entry, I assume that this is to ensure that the end time is after start time and that times don't overlap midnight.